# How to save query in multidimesional array?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this script executing as a cron job everyday to update days remaining to pay invoices. I first query every row of my table and attempt to store the data in a multidimensional array but this seems to be storing everything I query in the first element of my array.

Here's my script:

```
<?php
  include '../inc/dbinfo.inc';

  ini_set("log_errors", 1);
  ini_set("error_log", "/tmp/php-error.log");
  error_log( "#################################################     UpdateVendorInvoiceDays.php    #################################################" );

  $three = 3;

  $fetchAllInvoices = "SELECT VENDORINVOICEID, VdrInvoiceReceived, PaymentDue, COUNT(*), DATEDIFF(PaymentDue, NOW()) FROM tblVendorInvoices WHERE VdrInvoiceStatusID != ?";
  $getInvoices = $conn->prepare($fetchAllInvoices);
  $getInvoices->bind_param("i", $three);
  $getInvoices->execute();
  $result = $getInvoices->get_result();

  $rows = array();
  $j = 0;

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  {
    $rows[$j][] = $row;
    $j++;
  }

  echo json_encode($rows[0][0]);    //Only outputs one row

  //UPDATE DAYS REMAINING IN EACH ENTRY THAT ISNT PAID
  $updateDaysRemaining = "UPDATE tblVendorInvoices SET DaysRemaining = ? WHERE VENDORINVOICEID = ? AND VdrInvoiceStatusID ! = ?";
  $setDays = $conn->prepare($updateDaysRemaining);

  $k = 0; //incrementor
  $numberOfEntries = $rows['COUNT(*)'];

  for($k;$k<$numberOfEntries;$k++){
     $setDays->bind_param("iii", $rows[$k]["DATEDIFF(PaymentDue, NOW())"], 
     $rows[$k]['VENDORINVOICEID'], $three);
    if($setDays->execute()){
      error_log('Cron success');
    }else{
      error_log('Cron fail');
    }
  }
?>
```

Currently the output from my first query is:
`[[{"VENDORINVOICEID":88,"VdrInvoiceReceived":"2018-08-21","PaymentDue":"2018-07-27","COUNT(*)":2,"DATEDIFF(PaymentDue, NOW())":-25}]]`

and my error log only gives me a notice for `$rows['COUNT(*)']` being undefined (which makes sense)

I've looked at other answers here but they don't seem to have the same structure as I do.

EDIT: I also have 2 rows in my database but this only puts out one. I forgot to mention this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of simplifications to get all of the rows.  Instead of...

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
  {
    $rows[$j][] = $row;
    $j++;
  }

  echo json_encode($rows[0][0]);
```

You can just return all rows using [`fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)...

```
$rows = $result->fetch_all (MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Then encode the whole array and not just the one element - which is what `$rows[0][0]` was showing you.

As for you other problem - change in your select statement to

```
COUNT(*) as rowCount
```

and then you can use this alias for the field reference...

```
$rows['COUNT(*)']
```

becomes

```
$rows['rowCount']
```

Comment: This still gives me the same output other than the alias being added. I should have put `json_encode($rows)` in my post above. I had tried echoing just `$rows` previously and it was the same.

Comment: Can you add a screen print of the data in the table tblVendorInvoices.

Comment: Try removing the `COUNT(*) as rowCount` from the SQL, use `$result->num_rows` instead, see if this helps.

Comment: Okay, I got this to work now. Must have been a delay on my page or something, not quite sure. But there is a problem accessing my array variables. I can access `$row[0]['VENDORINVOICEID']` but I cannot access `$row[1]['VENDORINVOICEID']` Is this a problem with how the array is setup or is there a different way to access it?

Comment: Do you mean `$rows` and not `$row`?

Comment: No I'm just an idiot and reproduced the problem lol. Thank you for your help :) This worked